# Creating Separate Views For UISegmentedControl Buttons

Tags: ios, objective-c, view, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm struggling to create views for each `Segmented Buttons`.
The `Segmented control` button is inside one of the views from Tab Bar Controller. I'm creating it in StoryBoard.Already i've asked same question([Creating Separate Views For segmented Control Buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14847931/creating-separate-views-for-segmented-control-buttons))..         Waiting for solution..

Here is a screenshot of my storyboard.
[image]

Also I've tried `Editor->EmbedIn->NavController`, but it displays separately with navBar with Back button. I need those 3 views also within this same display (along with those NavBar and segment buttons).

For each view I've some functions as displaying list of images, Maps..so I'll need to design in UI also.is there any possibilities of creating new view controller according to ParentView size (like contentPlaceHolder)..because i need to design in ui..Thanks in Advance..

Comment: It's frowned upon here at SO to ask the same question twice. That being said, I would try to help you if I understood the question, but I don't. What do you mean by "create views for each Segmented Buttons" Do you mean each segment of your one button? What do you mean by views? Do you want to go to a different controller when a segment is tapped?

Comment: Another question. It looks like you have a navigation bar and a tool bar in the first controller. Is that correct? What are you using the nav bar for? For its title time?

Comment: s i want to go to a different controller when a segment is tapped!! but should be displayed within the same Controller..

Comment: I would do that with a container view then. You could add a container view in IB that takes up the space between the tab bar and your tool bar at the top. You could then switch out which controller was embedded in the container view when you tap on the segmented control.

Comment: @rdelmar - do you have any samples for that container view as you said to me?? waiting for your reply rdelmar..

Answer (score 1):

The code below shows how to switch out the controllers in a container view. In IB, I started with a tabbed template, added a navigation bar and tool bar to the top of FirstViewController, and added the segmented control to the tool bar. I then added a container view (next to the regular view in the objects list) to the view,  and sized it to take up all the space between the tab bar and the tool bar. I made outlets to the container view and the title item of the navigation bar, and connected the method, changeControllers: to the segmented control. When you add the container view, you automatically get a view controller of the same size connected to it with an embed segue. I added two more view controllers, changed their size to "Freeform", and adjusted their size to be the same as the embedded controller (320x411). This size change is for layout purposes in IB only, you still have to size the views in code when you add them to the container, as you can see below. This code is in FirstViewController, the controller with the container view:

```
@interface FirstViewController ()
@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *containerView;
@property (strong,nonatomic) UIViewController *embeddedVC;
@property (strong,nonatomic) UIViewController *secondVC;
@property (strong,nonatomic) UIViewController *thirdVC;
@property (strong,nonatomic) UIViewController *currentController;
@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UINavigationItem *titleItem;
@end

@implementation FirstViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.embeddedVC = self.childViewControllers.lastObject;
    self.currentController = self.embeddedVC;
    self.titleItem.title = self.currentController.title;
}


-(IBAction)ChangeControllers:(UISegmentedControl *)sender {

        switch (sender.selectedSegmentIndex) {
            case 0:{
                if (![self.currentController isEqual:self.embeddedVC]) {
                    self.embeddedVC.view.frame = self.containerView.bounds;
                    [self addChildViewController:self.embeddedVC];
                    [self moveToNewController:self.embeddedVC];
                }
                break;
            }
            case 1:{
                if (! self.secondVC) {
                    self.secondVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Second"];
                }
                if (![self.currentController isEqual:self.secondVC]) {
                    self.secondVC.view.frame = self.containerView.bounds;
                    [self addChildViewController:self.secondVC];
                    [self moveToNewController:self.secondVC];
                }
                break;
            }
            case 2:{
                if (! self.thirdVC) {
                    self.thirdVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Third"];
                }
                if (![self.currentController isEqual:self.thirdVC]) {
                    self.thirdVC.view.frame = self.containerView.bounds;
                    [self addChildViewController:self.thirdVC];
                    [self moveToNewController:self.thirdVC];
                }
                break;
            }
            default:
                break;
        }
}


-(void)moveToNewController:(id) newController {
    [self.currentController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
    [self transitionFromViewController:self.currentController toViewController:newController duration:.6 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft animations:^{}
                            completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                [self.currentController removeFromParentViewController];
                                [newController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
                                self.currentController = newController;
                                self.titleItem.title = self.currentController.title;
                            }];
}
```